# Azure function throwing exceptions when called even with default template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm baffled by how to just make a simple Azure function. In Visual Studio 2017 (I'm on version 15.5.6) I create a simple project following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs

My steps:

1. Make new Azure Functions project and leave the framework at the default of .Net Framework 4.6.1
2. On the next screen I choose HttpTrigger and the drop down says "Azure Functions v1 (.NET Framework)"
3. I set the storage to be my azure storage that I already created in the portal and set the authorization to "admin"

Everything compiles fine. I call the function via PostMan and get this error:

"A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'log'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value was provided for parameter 'log'."

For reference, here is the template function they created that I haven't modified at all:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace TestFunc
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            // Set name to query string or body data
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the "TraceWriter log" and the call to "log.Info(...." and then try again, I instead get this error:

"A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. TestFunc: Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.HttpStatusCode, !!0)'."

I've tried changing the .Net version to 4.7 but nothing changed. I tried changing the function version to v2 instead of v1 (even though it's in beta at the moment) but nothing happened either. The only NuGet package that's added by the template is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.6. There's an update to 1.0.7 available but that doesn't help either.

I have no idea what to try. This is the default template. I have another function project that works fine but that was done a while ago when VS2015 was the latest, and was during the time when you had to have those function.json files to make your precompiled DLL. I was hoping to be able to use the current system as it seems to be the best way going forward but if I can't get this to work I may just go back to the old way of doing things. Thanks.

Comment: OK well I think I fixed it. I don't know what the issue was, but after quitting and restarting VS a few times, and running the function app, THIS time I got a prompt saying there was a newer version of the function CLI. I updated and now it all works fine! I'm not sure why this wasn't installed. I had checked for VS updates and installed the azure function tooling update. Anyway, I suppose not deleting this topic may help others if they run into the same situation as me. If an admin feels otherwise feel free to nuke it.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like some version conflict